# React: Pass onClick function on all Children Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to fire an onClick function when I click on any of my children "postItem" components.  With what I have now, the clicked components won't do anything, unless the onClick function is outside the map function (such as in a new separate component)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import PostItem from "./postItem";
import "../styles/socialFeed.css";

class SocialFeed extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { posts: [] };
    this.showBox = this.showBox.bind(this);
  }

  showBox(postItem) {
    console.log(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.Posts();
  }

  Posts() {
    axios
      .get(
        "randomapi"
      )
      .then(res => {
        const posts = res.data.data;
        this.setState({ posts });
      });
  }

  render() {
    let { posts } = this.state;
    let allPosts = posts.map(post => (
      <PostItem key={post.id} {...post} onClick={this.showBox} />
    ));
    return <div className="social-feed">{allPosts}</div>;
  }
}

export default SocialFeed;
```

is it incorrect to pass a function through a map?

Comment: It's correct. Add ur `PostItem` code.

Comment: what do you mean? when i click on a postitem, i dont get anything logged.  When I make a new separate component with just the onclick function, it logs.

Comment: maybe something wrong with your `PostItem`.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with your `onClick` being inside a map. Remember that when you're thinking in ecma, functions are first-class: passing a function around as a prop is no different than a string or an array, and those are okay to map, right?

The problem appears to be the arguments passed to the `SocialFeed#showBox` method. Your method is defined as taking `showItem` as the arg, but `onClick` will pass the React `SyntheticEvent` object as its first arg. While you technically *can* get the `target` from that, this may or may not be what you want to show the box (probably not).

What you'll usually want to do, is [pass in an argument to the event handler](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html), e.g.:

```
<PostItem key={post.id} {...post} onClick={() => this.showBox(post)} />
```

Comment: so i tried this, and that definitely makes sense in how you explain passing a function is exactly the same as passing an array or variable.

now when i do as you said. it doesnt console.log anything, but the props of all of the children now contain an onClick method

Comment: check your PostItem and make sure the onClick is passed into a component that's clickable, eg `const PostItem = ({ onClick, title }) => <div><h1 {...{ onClick }}>{title}</h1></div>;`